# Apache pig: How to use the ignoreBadFiles tag with the load function?

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I see there's a tag called ignoreBadFiles for the load function of Apache pig. I am wondering if someone can show me an example how to use it. 
Here's the link for the jira tickets:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3404
It discusses the use cases for this tag but does not have an example.
For something like:

```
LOAD '$inpath' USING AvroStorage();
```

It would be great if someone can show me how to use this tag with the load function. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The ticket is still open and unresolved,meaning that the feature is not yet part of apache pig.

Comment: @VK_217 Sorry I pasted the wrong apache pig tickets. Please see this one https://issues-test.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2909?attachmentOrder=desc. I tried the example mentioned in testavrostorage file by doing `USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage ('ignore_bad_files');` but it's giving me an `can not instantiate avrostorage with 'ignore_bad_files error'`. Can you take a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless you're abbreviating the error message, you should be seeing could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage' with arguments '[ignore_bad_files]'.   Otherwise, maybe you're not passing the full classname.  In my local environment, using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('ignore_bad_files') does instantiate without an error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to getting your AvroStorage('ignore_bad_files') working, you may want to look at setting mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent.  This would give similar results by allowing the job continue with certain % of mappers (readers) failing.

Comment: Hi, do I set it in the pig script or somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: Would be great if you can suggest some readings on these settings. I figured out that my server is using an outdated pig so it does not support the ignore_bad_files tag. Thanks a lot!